# How to get host+base from angular $location

Tags: angularjs

I have angular application located in directory 'someApp'. Url is `http://example-domain/someApp/#/` for some state url with path is: `http://example-domain/someApp/#/user/login`. I there "angular way" to get this part `http://example-domain/someApp/`

```
var redirectUri = $location.absUrl();
redirectUri = redirectUri.substr(0, redirectUri.indexOf('#'));
```

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to use

```
window.location.origin + window.location.pathname
```

which would return `http://example-domain/someApp`

This will provide the entire base url, even if using virtual directories/paths.
However, IE does not support origin.  As a result, you could concatenate the components of the url to give you the base directory like so:

```
window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname
```

which would return `http://example-domain/someApp`

If using virtual directories, you will have difficulty using `$location`, since `$location.path()` returns AFTER the hash and `$location.host()` will only return the domain, not the domain and the directory, which is what `window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname` gives you.

Comment: Great answer, I would just use window.location.host instead of hostname in case you use a non standart port.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use:

```
 location.origin + location.pathname
```

Say the url is http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo

```
$location.protocol(); // will give: http
$location.host();     // will give: example.com
location.host         // will give: example.com:8080
$location.port();     // will give: 8080
$location.path();     // will give: /some/path
$location.url();      // will give: /some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
```

See the full [detail](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: I know that. What if my url is `http://example.com/myApp/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo` and I want `http://example.com/myApp`

Answer (score 0):

for angular 2 or higher

```
location.hash      ➡️ #/some/path
location.protocol; ➡️ http: or https:
location.hostname; ➡️ example.com
location.host;     ➡️ example.com:8080
location.port;     ➡️ 8080
location.href;     ➡️ http://example.com:8080/#/some/path
location.origin;   ➡️ http://example.com:8080
location.path;     ➡️ /
```